# Getting all project drawables

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm trying to get all the drawables that I have stored in res/drawable-mdpi (and -hdpi, etc.).
I saw the following code online:

```
    Field[] ID_Fields = android.R.drawable.class.getFields();
    int[] resArray = new int[ID_Fields.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < ID_Fields.length; i++) {
        try {
            resArray[i] = ID_Fields[i].getInt(null);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But this only gets all android drawables, not the ones in my folders. How can I access all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets android drawables because you use `android.R.drawable`.
If you want to get your drawables use `your.packagename.R.drawable`

Answer (score 2):

the reason it only gets the Android drawables is because you're using the `android.R` package in your declaration

```
Field[] ID_Fields = android.R.drawable.class.getFields();
```

you should use

```
Field[] ID_Fields = R.drawable.class.getFields();
```

instead.